# xp client problem

Tags: windows-server-2008

I used to have as a file server for my clients recently and switched to windows server 2008 and I faced strange problem
My win7 clients have no problem but xp client get disconnected about 2-3 time a day. I had not any problem when I had server2003, this problem starts when I changed my server from 2003 to 2008, be sure that the is no any network problem, ping in both side are under 1ms

Comment: We need more info than this, any errors? Event log messages?

Comment: When you say 'disconnected' - what is the client seeing?  Mapped network drive becomes disconnected, or something else?

Comment: Are they domain users? http://serverfault.com/questions/85328/windows-server-2008-share-not-accessible suggests it could be SEP/SAV, what AV are you running?

Comment: hello
no,not any event is logged.,they only use sharefolder not mapped network. 
No I don't install AD for serve they have office group only 
but ping in two side are  good , when they type the server address in RUN like \\servername\sharename  the name and pass form doesn't appear or if they was connected when they click on the share folder  their computer  be hanged and the net work will be slow

Comment: I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please check  through [Windows Server 2008 does not use CIFS to connect to network shares](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverfiles/thread/a0c533f5-100d-4a5f-91d3-bbcb5d47aaf0) (and sublinks there)  for possible causes and solutions.

---

---**Update1:**
See also:

- [Computer disappeared from Workgroup](https://serverfault.com/questions/87162/computer-disappeared-from-workgroup)

which basically tells that you must have WINS server (or dynamic DNS) server.

From my experience, I cannot see my own PC in "My Network Places" in WindowsExplorer without WINS

- [cannot access my own computer through My Network Places](https://superuser.com/questions/164003/cannot-access-my-own-computer-through-my-network-places)

Comment: tank you I shall check and try.